# Feature request: grayed-out diamond for ex-moderators

Tags: feature-request

Let's make a grayed-out (meaning: inactive control ;-) ) diamond for Bill the Lizard, symbolizing his ex-moderator status. This could be used for other ex-mods as well - after all, they will never be normal users here :-).

Comment: What do you mean by "they will never be normal users here"?

Comment: Can't speak for Bill but pretty sure that he stepped down because he *wants* to be a normal user.  Unlike some mods that don't resign but just never show up.  Let him.

Comment: Moderators get a special badge: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3109/sheriff

Comment: Totally agree.  Should be **""**